# Software to combine multiple similar photos and choose the best parts from each

Tags: image-processing, photography, image-editor, photoshop

Windows Live Gallery had a [great Photo Fuse feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tis_G1loFto) that allowed you to select multiple similar photos and be able to select which faces from each photo would be used in the final composite image. This was great for group photos where in every photo someone isn't looking at the camera or blinking etc, as you can combine them all and select all the faces that are looking.

Unfortunately, Windows Live Gallery is now [unsupported and unavailable for download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18614/windows-essentials). Is there any free software that has similar functionality (offline/online)?

Comment: This question is too old to migrate, but you can create it again if you believe it will get more attention on another site. Actually, rather than that, I think you should explain in more details what you want to achieve, and change the question's title to that, instead of referencing defunct software that few people use nowadays.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have taken 3 (for instance) pictures of the same group with the same angle/etc, and want an app to take all the smiling faces from the 3 pictures and make a single picture where everyone is smiling?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Yes that is correct. I've modified the question title and I'll leave it here for a bit longer.

Comment: How do you mean, it is no longer available for download? I just Googled & it certainly seems to be available. Maybe not from Microsoft, but from other sites